# why my web api is working on https not http in C#

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I have created a project in .net framework, it is working well on https://localhost:44309/api/office but it is giving following error on http://localhost:44309/api/office

```
GET http://localhost:44309/api/Office
Error: read ECONNRESET
```

Comment: You can't do HTTPS and HTTP on the same port. You will need to configure your web server to use a different port for HTTP. You get the error as the browser is not expecting to have to negotiate a secure connection.

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS aren't served on the same port.

Comment: In Visual Studio, the 443nn ports are used for SSL.  There will be another port for non-SSL, typically something like 56614, which you can find in project Properties > Debug.

Comment: You shouldn't be using HTTP!!!  If server is HTTPS than the application should be secure and only used HTTPS.

Comment: Probably what is confusing here is that online you can usually just swap out http for https without having to change anything else; that is because for those sites http and https are configured on the default ports, so the browser will itself go either to port 80 or port 443 depending on the scheme. But you specify a manual port in your url so you need to specify the correct https port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running from Visual Studio, you should see the various URLs for http and https. They cannot be on the same port. Click on your project and check the Project Properties section as seen in the snapshot below.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgkAv.png)